# NavigationController pushViewController doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

```
 GetNeedItemsViewController *getNeedItemsViewController = [[GetNeedItemsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetNeedItemsViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:getNeedItemsViewController animated:YES];
```

[image]

I dont know why the getNeedItemsViewController doesn't displayed.

Help me with this, thank you in advance!

Comment: That's not a lot to go off, can you give any more information that might be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added content on the `GetNeedItemsViewController`? From the image it looks like it is added but that it is empty. And at the moment you have a memory leak. One option is to `auto-release` it the controller.

Comment: Yeah,I made a mistake...Thank you!